# TableView with 2 sections, Can't passing Data to Section2ViewController

Tags: swift

I have a TableView with 2 sections, Each sections connects to another ViewController, The first section with the name segue.identifier == "schowDetail" Works flawlessly, but the second section:segue.identifier == "section2segue" does not work. I have written the code that I find right @IBOutlet weak var textlabel: UILabel! in to The Section2ViewController, he should show the text from MasterViewController prepareforsegue, but instead he just shows label in the Section2ViewController, Am I doing something wrongin the performsegue? or where are the problem.

I upload [link form MasterViewController](https://github.com/sten-danli/OhrakupunkturFinished/blob/master/CandySearch/MasterViewController.swift), and Code From Section2ViewController ,code from prepareforsegue. and [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtAFm.jpg) from Main.storyboard, maybe that helps to explain something better.

```
class Section2ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textlabel: UILabel!

var Section1Index : Section1Index? {

    didSet {
        configureView()
    }
}
func configureView() {
    if let Section1Index = Section1Index {
        if let textlabel = textlabel {
            textlabel.text=Section1Index.name
            print("hier ist:\(Section1Index.name)")
        }
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureView()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "showDetail"{
  if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    let candy: Indications
    if isFiltering() {
      candy = filteredCandies[indexPath.row]
    } else {
      candy = indication[indexPath.row]
    }
    let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
    controller.detailIndications = candy
    controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
    controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
  }
}else if segue.identifier=="section2segue"{
    if let s2v=segue.destination as? Section2ViewController{
         s2v.Section1Index=sender as? Section1Index
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this in masterviewcontroller

```
    import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet var searchFooter: SearchFooter!

  var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
  var indication = [Indications]()
  var filteredCandies = [Indications]()
  let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

  var section1=[Section1Index]()


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true

    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Magendarmbeschwerden", "Mund- und Rachenraum", "Other"]
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchFooter

    section1 = [
        Section1Index(name: "Was ist Ohrakupunktur", beschreibung: "Ohrakupunktur ist ..."),
        Section1Index(name: "Wie mach ich das", beschreibung: "So machen Sie das ..."),
        Section1Index(name: "was brauch ich", beschreibung: "Das brauchen Sie ...")

    ]

    indication = [
        Indications(category: "Magendarmbeschwerden", name: "Bauchschmerzen", numOfPoint: "6", indication: "Kopfschmerzen", beschreibung: "Die akute Bronchitis ist eine akute, in der Regel infektionsbedingte Entzündung der Atemwege, welche sich im Bereich der Bronchien abspielt. Bei Mitbeteiligung der Luftröhre (Trachea) spricht man von einer Tracheobronchitis.KopfschmerzenDie akute Bronchitis ist eine akute, in der Regel infektionsbedingte Entzündung der Atemwege, welche sich im Bereich der Bronchien abspielt. Bei Mitbeteiligung der Luftröhre (Trachea) spricht man von einer Tracheobronchitis.KopfschmerzenDie akute Bronchitis ist eine akute, in der Regel infektionsbedingte Entzündung der Atemwege, welche sich im Bereich der Bronchien abspielt. Bei Mitbeteiligung der Luftröhre (Trachea) spricht man von einer Tracheobronchitis.KopfschmerzenDie akute Bronchitis ist eine akute, in der Regel infektionsbedingte Entzündung der Atemwege, welche sich im Bereich der Bronchien abspielt. Bei Mitbeteiligung der Luftröhre (Trachea) spricht man von einer Tracheobronchitis.Kopfschmerzen"),

        Indications(category: "Endokrine", name: "Alkoholkonsum", numOfPoint: "6", indication: "Kopfschmerzen", beschreibung: "Die akute Bronchitis ist eine akute, in der Regel infektionsbedingte Entzündung der Atemwege, welche sich im Bereich der Bronchien abspielt. Bei Mitbeteiligung der Luftröhre (Trachea) spricht man von einer Tracheobronchitis.."),
      ]

    if let splitViewController = splitViewController {
      let controllers = splitViewController.viewControllers
      detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if splitViewController!.isCollapsed {
      if let selectionIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: selectionIndexPath, animated: animated)
      }
    }
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0{
        return section1.count
    }else if isFiltering() {
      searchFooter.setIsFilteringToShow(filteredItemCount: filteredCandies.count, of: indication.count)
      return filteredCandies.count
    }
    searchFooter.setNotFiltering()
    return indication.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellID=["Cell2","Cell"][indexPath.section]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)
    let candy: Indications
    if indexPath.section==0{
        cell.textLabel?.text=section1[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }else if isFiltering(){
        candy = filteredCandies[indexPath.row]
    } else {
      candy = indication[indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.textLabel!.text = candy.name
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = candy.category
        return cell
  }


  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail"{
      if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let candy: Indications
        if isFiltering() {
          candy = filteredCandies[indexPath.row]
        } else {
          candy = indication[indexPath.row]
        }
        let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
        controller.detailIndications = candy
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
      }
    }else if segue.identifier=="section2segue"{
        let s2v = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! Section2ViewController
            let section1IndexName = sender as! UITableViewCell
        print(section1IndexName.textLabel?.text)
        s2v.section1Index = (section1IndexName.textLabel?.text)! //your sender is a UITableViewCell
        }
    }


  func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredCandies = indication.filter({( candy : Indications) -> Bool in
      let doesCategoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (candy.category == scope)

      if searchBarIsEmpty() {
        return doesCategoryMatch
      } else {
        return doesCategoryMatch && candy.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
      }
    })
    tableView.reloadData()
  }

  func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
    return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
  }

  func isFiltering() -> Bool {
    let searchBarScopeIsFiltering = searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex != 0
    return searchController.isActive && (!searchBarIsEmpty() || searchBarScopeIsFiltering)
  }
}
extension MasterViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
  }
}

extension MasterViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
  }
}
```

and in the Section2

```
import UIKit

class Section2ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var textlabel: UILabel!

    var section1Index: String? {
        didSet {
            configureView()
            print("DID SET CALLED \(section1Index)")
        }
    }
    func configureView() {
        if let section1IndexUnwrapped = section1Index {
            print("Section name is: \(section1IndexUnwrapped)")
            if let textlabel = textlabel {
                textlabel.text = section1IndexUnwrapped
                print("hier ist:\(section1IndexUnwrapped)")
            }
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureView()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, but it still does not work, I'm really crazy now, the text label show nothing at all.

Comment: Just change the code like i showed you it will work pay attention to the variable naming I changed . I have downloaded your code and changed it like above and it worked

Comment: For sure I have recoded your code in my project, But the Section2ViewController only show "label" on the display, He should show "name" from " section1 = [
        Section1Index(name: "Was ist Ohrakupunktur", beschreibung: "Ohrakupunktur ist ...")]

Comment: Check properly because i habe changed both view controllers the second one has a sting now instead of your struct

Comment: Yes, I checked every code.I have now updated my project in GitHub, which is the new code after the change. Can you read it again? Maybe I missed something.Thank you again for your help！

Comment: Give me a little time and I post both view controllers as I changed them

Comment: I apologize first, Because I can only now test the code, My Xcode needs yesterday absolutely an Update, It took a ver long time.

Comment: I just Coping and Pasting the code to my Project, But it just shows only "label" not content from MasterView.

Comment: is it on github??

Comment: yes Hier is  the link to My Project:  https://github.com/sten-danli/OhrakupunkturFinished

Comment: are you running the simulator on an iPad??

Comment: on iPhone8 plus

Comment: wait i will check in simulator and upload the change to github as it works on my computer

Comment: I have now tried simulator with ipad, but the same trouble.

Comment: just download it from here https://github.com/verebes1/OhrakupunkturFinished-master and run should work

Comment: it could be a weird xcode bug or I changed something in the storyboard what I cannot remember :)

Comment: I'm almost crazy now, it works !!! I am goin to study your code now!!!! Thanx you my Friend, You have helped me so much!!!

Comment: I have sent a pull request to your github with the good code feel free to accept it and accept my answer here as well. Thank you

Comment: watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppNZoEOr0zs&index=7&list=PLsJq-VuSo2k26duIWzNjXztkZ7VrbppkT       lecture 6 and 7 should help you. If you want to learn more then go into itunes and get Stanford IOS 11 it is free and very informative

Comment: Trank You so mach for your help and this useful recommendations,I will do that.

Answer (score -1):

```
else if segue.identifier=="section2Segue"{
            let s2v = segue.destination as! Section2ViewController
            let section1IndexName = sender as! UITableViewCell
            print(section1IndexName.textLabel?.text)
            s2v.section1Index = (section1IndexName.textLabel?.text)! 
        }
```

Update ur code to this. it cant pass the data because it did crash on

```
let s2v = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! Section2ViewController
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot for your response! I have modified this way, but still can not Passing data to Section2ViewController.